# Ajax Post not finding method in page model

Tags: c#, ajax, razor-pages

I have the following method inside my page model which is called Order

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAddRecord(string recordId)
 {
     return new JsonResult("Hello");
 }
```

My `Ajax` code to call said method:

```
$('#RecordList').change(function () {

        var formData = {
            recordId: $("#RecordList").val(),
        };

          $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            data: formData,
            url: '@Url.Page("order", "addrecord")',
            success: function (result) {
                alert(result)
            },
            error: function (result) { }
          });


    });
```

Yet when it's fired it returns StatusCode 400, however, I have another `Ajax` method on the same page that works successfully, the difference is that one is a GET whereas this is a POST.

I really can't see what the problem is here.

Comment: add HttpPost attribute above OnPostAddRecord action

Comment: @mehmetx the warning I get is HttpPostAttribute cannot be applied to Razor Page handler methods, Routes for Razor Pages must be declared using the page directive or using conventions

Comment: You can add `[IgnoreAntiforgeryToken]` above your `OnPostAddRecord`,or you can add AntiforgeryToken like  @MikeBrind.

Answer (score 1):

You need to include the request verification token in your FormData: https://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/336/ajax-posts-in-razor-pages-and-http-400-errors

Comment: The page has no authentication on it.

Comment: Request verification has nothing to do with authentication